# No wireless extensions in ubuntu

Tags: wireless

Basically I'm an information security student and I was trying to set up snort, I needed to turn off “Large Receive Offload” (lro) and “Generic Receive Offload” (gro) to get snort working which I have successfully done and edited `/etc/network/interfaces` and everything was working fine.

Minutes later my wifi went down and I have tried every single command to get it back up without any use, I undid all the changes I have made yet its not working.

when I type `iwconfig` this is what I get

```
lo no wireless extensions.

wlo1 IEEE 802.11bgn ESSID:o ff/any 
Mode:Managed Access Point: Not-Associated       Tx-Power=0 dBm 
Retry short limit:7 RTS thr:o ff Fragment thr: off
Encryption key:o ff
Power Management:o ff

eno1 no wireless extensions.
```

I tried to get the network up as well but I get `error: input/output`.

I've been going through this for about 6 hours now without success, my wired connection works but wireless doesn't.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Download [this script](http://askubuntu.com/a/425205/522934) and [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/786244/edit) your question to include a link to the pastebin output. This way people can have an overview.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to check whether the device is for some reason blocked by RF-KILL? Is there a physical switch for WiFi on your computer (mine is <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> for "airplane mode" which is triggered by default on new Ubuntu installations, every time). Try:

```
rfkill list all
```

Also, Make sure you are using

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid (network) key (passwd)
sudo dhclient wlan0
```

This is the only way I've been able to (consistently) get WiFi back up and running. If you run the command `lshw` and see a wireless interface, you know it's at least detected... so you are safe.

*Substitute `wlan0` for whatever the name of your wireless device is

Comment: tried rfkill list all repeatedly, i get

Comment: What is it that you get?

Comment: tried rfkill list all repeatedly, i get
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
and same with up command i get 

SIOCSIFFLAGS: Input/output error

and for sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid (network) key (passwd)

i keep getting invalid argument for my password

lastly sudo dhclient wlan0

i get 
RTNETLINK answers: Input/output error

Comment: I forgot to specify (although I'm sure you did): replace (network) with network name, and (passwd) with that network's password. This doesn't seem to be the issue in your case, but definitely make sure that's right, as it's a logical first step in troubleshooting your issue.

Comment: Do you see your wireless device when you run `sudo lshw`?

Comment: yeah i replaced the name and password, and yup its right there but i dont seem to be able to get it working 

-network DISABLED
                description: Wireless interface
                product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe

Comment: Well... are you using network-manager (or network-manager-gnome)? I solved a few WiFi issues by simply switching to wicd
`sudo apt-get install wicd`

Comment: I understand that's not as much as an answer as it is a workaround, but it's a solution nonetheless (potentially)...

Comment: i did that, wicd couldnt find wireless network either :)

Comment: geez... well have you tried reverting back to original settings (before installation of snort)... since THAT configuration worked? Are these the only new packages:
libdaq2
oinkmaster
snort
snort-common
snort-common-libraries
snort-rules-default
?

Comment: I see I'm not likely to be able to help on this one... those are my intermediate troubleshooting skills. I would try to uninstall the program and see if that fixes it. I could try to install it and see if it breaks anything if I get a VM up and running... can't afford it otherwise (I'm a web developer) :D but... I'm trying to research it some more for you.

Comment: i reverted /etc/network/interfaces to how it was even removed ethtool incase somehow it was the cause, and i had to add many new packages for snort but everything was working just fine after every step until i decided to edit the interface file and turn off both IRO and GRO.

Comment: thanks for the effort mate i truly appreciate it! i really don't want to uninstall ubnutu and reinstall it so many stuff i have going on on it and no dont go as far as installing it just to check leave it mate dont bother yourself you did more than enough

Comment: haha well, no worries at all! Surely someone will come along and be able to answer, maybe a sysadmin who's used snort... surely you can't be the ONLY one! Cheers, and best of luck with it then.

Comment: Cheers! it's been fun seeing you getting frustrated with me about this! best of luck with your web developing applications as well i don't think you're having it any easier than me

Comment: :D True story my friend. We love the struggle.

Answer (score -1):

okay so, after two days and countless hours spent trying to get the wireless back up its finally working. Not sure if this is an actual answer to the question but here you go this is how i got it working again incase someone is ever in the same frustrating spot as me. 
i made sure i deleted every single package i have installed for snort, including

```
flex
bison
tcpdumb
libpac
pulledpork
pcap
pcre
libdnet
```

and then ran this command to make sure i delete all traces of snort and its dependencies

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove snort
```

and did the same command for every single package up there

then i rebooted the pc, still nothing worked. Then giving up i decided to format ubnutu, so i log into my windwos since i dual boot for the first time since this whole fiasco happened and that was the solution. Somehow, logging into my windows participation then back into my ubuntu fixed the issue.

i wanna thanks p Smith for his help, he's the one who suggested to revert back to settings before snort and remove all packages which could have helped solve the problem.

if anyone faces similar problem, please up this post or pm me and ill try to guide you through this.